# Add new list-item to <ul>

Tags: javascript, html

When I write in something in the prompt I get underfined. When I write something in the prompt I want that to add in the list like a new list-element. For example if I write "Food" in the prompt I want it to say "Food" on the second line. Now it adds a new list-element but it's empty.
Here is my code:

```js
var items = document.querySelector('items');

function addItemToList() {
  var newItem = prompt("Add item to list");
  if (newItem != null) {
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = li.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li>Drinks</li>
</ul>
<input class="buttom-add" type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Item" onclick="addItemToList()">
```

Comment: Do -> `document.querySelector('#items'); ` and use `items.appendChild(li);` in your function.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the newly appended `li`'s `innerHTML` to its `value` property (which is 0) instead of the value returned by `prompt`.

Instead, assign `newItem` to the `li`'s `innerHTML` property:

```js
var items = document.querySelector('items');

function addItemToList() {
  var newItem = prompt("Add item to list");
  if (newItem != null) {
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = newItem;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li>Drinks</li>
</ul>
<input class="buttom-add" type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Item" onclick="addItemToList()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the last line with `li.innerHTML = newItem;` so that you assign the item read from the prompt.

```js
var items = document.querySelector('items');

function addItemToList() {
  var newItem = prompt("Add item to list");
  if (newItem != null) {
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = newItem;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li>Drinks</li>
</ul>
<input class="buttom-add" type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Item" onclick="addItemToList()">
```